# How to build codegen types from typeDefs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, graphql, graphql-codegen

I am trying to use [graphql-codegen](https://www.the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen) to generate my Typescript types by pointing it at my GraphQL type definitions.

However, I appear to get the error:

```
Failed to load schema from code file "./src/typeDefs.ts": Syntax Error: Expected Name, found "}".
GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found "}".
```

My codegen config is pointing at my typeDefs file

```yaml
schema: "./src/typeDefs.ts"
generates:
  ./src/types.d.ts:
    config:
      useIndexSignature: true
    plugins:
      - typescript
      - typescript-resolvers
require:
  - tsconfig-paths/register
```

And my typeDefs looks like this:

```js
import { gql } from "apollo-server";

const typeDefs = gql`
  type A { name: String }
`;

export default typeDefs;
```

I can get it to work if I create a schema.graphql file like so:

```
type A { name: String }
```

However, I need to be able to build some of my GraphQL enums from other sources like so:

```js
import { gql } from "apollo-server";
import { Allergens } from "@prisma/client";

const allergens = Object.values(Allergens).join(" ");

const typeDefs = gql`

  enum Allergens {
    ${allergens}
  }

`;
```

So I can't have my schema in a .graphql file as I need to write it programmatically in a javascript file.

Is there a way to generate my TS types from the typeDefs generated from `gql`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm Charly, from The Guild, working on GraphQL Code Generator.

Loading a Schema definition from TypeScript files can be achieved by `require: ['ts-node/register']` as documented here: https://www.the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen/docs/config-reference/require-field#typescript-support